# Unable to retrieve the Value from the XML from the root element

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was working on the xml to retrieve the data using sql server, but I was not able to retrieve the correct values from the query which is listed below.

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML,
        @hDoc AS INT
set @XML = '
<root>
        <a>
            <b>Name</b>
            <y>
                <c>
                    <d>M</d>
                </c>
            </y>
            <e>Test1</e>
        </a>
        <a>
            <b>CX</b>
            <e>Test</e>
        </a>
</root>
'
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT a.d, a.b, a.e
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'root/a')
WITH 
(
d [nvarchar](20) '//y/c/d',
b [nvarchar](500) 'b',
e [nvarchar](500) 'e'
) a 

-- the output of this query is 
d   b   e
M   Name    Test1
M   CX  Test
```

The problem was that I want the corresponding value of `<d>`, but wherever, the `<d>` is not provided, it will return the value "M". I need the value NULL wherever the `<d>` value is not provided.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'root/a', 2)` to indicate that when elements do not exist to return null?

Comment: @vmachan Thanks for your help. I tried it now and its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    a.d, 
    a.b, 
    a.e
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'root/a')
WITH 
(
d [nvarchar](20) 'y/c/d',
b [nvarchar](500) 'b',
e [nvarchar](500) 'e'
) a
```